# Primary keys of table

Tags: primary-key

I have 2 keys in a DB table,

1. Country
2. employee id
3. region

What is the ideal sequence of the primary keys?  Which one will help `SELECT` run with better performance?

Comment: Are there two or three keys? You say two, but there are three in the list? The key that will help your SELECT statement depends greatly on the SELECT statement. Please add that to the question.

Comment: You need to learn *much* more before "performance" matters.